# How to get Update Status from Update Engine Service?

Tags: java, android

I want to use Update Engine Service via [UpdateEngine class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/UpdateEngine.java).

This class allows me to bind the update engine service like this:

```java
updateEngine.bind(new UpdateEngineCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusUpdate(int status, float v) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPayloadApplicationComplete(int status) {

            }
        }, new Handler()) ;
```

I need to know the status of the service when I bind it. UpdateEngine class has no such function as getStatus().

Is this onStatusUpdate callback guaranteed to be called at least once so that we can know the status when we first bind to the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is guaranteed for specific version of Android, but looking [this source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/update_engine/+/refs/heads/master/binder_service_android.cc), seems like it calls onStatusUpdate function at least once unless no update attempted so far.

```
Status BinderUpdateEngineAndroidService::bind(
    const android::sp<IUpdateEngineCallback>& callback, bool* return_value) {
  callbacks_.emplace_back(callback);
  const android::sp<IBinder>& callback_binder =
      IUpdateEngineCallback::asBinder(callback);
  auto binder_wrapper = android::BinderWrapper::Get();
  binder_wrapper->RegisterForDeathNotifications(
      callback_binder,
      base::Bind(
          base::IgnoreResult(&BinderUpdateEngineAndroidService::UnbindCallback),
          base::Unretained(this),
          base::Unretained(callback_binder.get())));
  // Send an status update on connection (except when no update sent so far),
  // since the status update is oneway and we don't need to wait for the
  // response.
  if (last_status_ != -1)
    callback->onStatusUpdate(last_status_, last_progress_);
  *return_value = true;
  return Status::ok();
}
```

If any better answer comes up, I will chose it as accepted.